# Discord.NET: Message.Edit method doesn't work

Tags: c#, server, edit, discord, discord.net

the method to edit a message won't work and I have no idea why.
Here is my command:

```
cService.CreateCommand("edit")
                .Do(async (e) =>
                {
                    await e.Message.Edit("edited!");
                });
```

And here is the error I get:

> [Error] [MessageQueue] Failed to edit message Server/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   Discord.Net.HttpException: The server responded with error 403 (Forbidden) at Discord.Net.Rest.RestSharpEngine.d__10.MoveNext()

with 10 more lines.

Everything else seems to work. That is the only issue I had which I can't tell what's wrong.

I'd be grateful if you tell me what mistake I've made. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should have more information about what happened. The library [passes along](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/blob/master/src/Discord.Net/MessageQueue.cs#L177) the exception information.

Comment: Yes, here is the exception information:
`Discord.Net.HttpException: The server responded with error 403 (Forbidden) at Discord.Net.Rest.RestSharpEngine.<Send>d__10.MoveNext()` with 10 more lines.
Why is it forbidden? I am sure the bot has all the permissions required. It can delete any message, but it cannot edit any message. What is going on? Thanks for the comment by the way!

Comment: You can't edit another users message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are [forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) from editing that message because Discord only allows the author of a message to edit it. Other users can't edit it and other bots can't edit it.

This is explained [here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#edit-message) in Discord's official API documentation:

> You can only edit messages that have been sent by the current user.

Comment: This has potential to be a good answer. Please provide link to documentation where it explains that other users can't edit a post.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech The answer has been edited to include this.

Answer (score 1):

With discord, a 403 error means that the bot had insufficient permissions and/or arguements to complete the task. With your command, are you specifying a message in which to edit.. you can only edit messages you have created with the bot. You can not use the bot to edit messages you or others have sent from your personal discord accounts.